# How do you make a SSD cache for a Raid 5 HDD array Ubuntu NAS?

Tags: server, hard-drive, ssd, raid, cache

I'm trying to make a NAS in Ubuntu as I like the OS more, and I can install it on a partition of a drive, as opposed to FreeNAS or any dedicated NAS operating systems.

However, one thing I liked about FreeNAS is its ability to designate a drive/SSD in your system as a data cache.

Is there any way to do a similar thing in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution to this as i too want to use my nvme drive as a read and write cache

Answer (score 0):

the more obvious way to achieve your goal is to use lvm2.

Lvm (logical volume manager) now in version 2 integrate dm-cache and is able to attach a certain amount (or size) of SSD device (raw or as RAID1 ou RAID10) so you can optimize your read on your main storage using a SSD area has cache.

I recommend reading this documentation even if its not ubuntu [ENABLING CACHING TO IMPROVE LVM PERFORMANCE](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/enabling-caching-to-improve-logical-volume-performance_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes)